# Библиотека PHPWord - сохранение шаблона для загрузки

Tags: php, phpword

Вопрос достаточно простой, но ввиду 3х дневного головомойства никак не могу прийти к решению.

Суть - есть библиотека PHPWord она умеет работать с шаблонами .docx. ОК!
Далее:
Создаю объект

```
$phpword = new PHPWord();
```

открываю шаблон

```
$tpl = $phpword->loadTemplate('tpl.docx');
```

В нем расставлены переменные по типу `${var}`

В PHP коде делаю как надо

```
$tpl->setValue('var', 'Вставка данных на место переменной');
```

В конце, когда переменные вставлены нужно сохранить получившийся файл

```
$tpl->save('mydoc.docx');
```

В библиотеке PHPWord можно передавать документ сразу на скачивание, если его генерация идет на лету вот таким вот способом

```
$writer = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($phpword, 'Word2007');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

Вопрос: **Можно ли так же сделать с созданным шаблоном без его сохранения на диск?**

Пробовал засунуть вместо объекта `$phpword` - `$tpl`: получал вот такую строчку

```
$phpword = new PHPWord();
$tpl = $phpword->loadTemplate('tpl.docx');
$tpl->setValue('var', 'Вставка данных на место переменной');
$writer = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($tpl, 'Word2007');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

пробовал

```
$tpl->save('php://output');
```

ничего не вышло. Может Вы подскажете?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/252057/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0-phpword-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

> Можно ли так же сделать с созданным шаблоном без его сохранения на диск?

Если посмотрите код `TemplateProcessor`, то заметите что он всегда создает временный файл и работает уже с ним, вызов `save()` (у неё, кстати, нет параметров) же просто возвращает путь к этому временному файлу (а вот `saveAs()` позволяет переименовать этот временный файл во что-то нужное вам).

Поэтому ответ: **нельзя**.

> задан "1 год назад"

Не заметил... ну да ладно, с тех пор все равно ничего не поменялось :)

Answer (score 1):

Как я сделал:

```
    $template->save('1.docx');

    function file_force_download($file) {
      if (file_exists($file)) {
        // сбрасываем буфер вывода PHP, чтобы избежать переполнения памяти выделенной под скрипт
        // если этого не сделать файл будет читаться в память полностью!
        if (ob_get_level()) {
          ob_end_clean();
        }
        // заставляем браузер показать окно сохранения файла
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        // читаем файл и отправляем его пользователю
        readfile($file);
        exit;
      }
    }

    file_force_download('1.docx');

    unlink('1.docx');
```

Создал и сохранил в файл, отправил пользователю и удалил.
Не знаю на сколько это эффективно, но мою проблему решило быстро.